# Routing non restfull controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have this controller:

**gods_controller.rb**

```
class GodsController < ApplicationController
  def notifications
    @reviews= Review.where("flag = ?", true)    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb      
    end
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :gods, :only => [:index] do
   get :notifications      
end
```

That route gives me this: http://example.com/gods/1/notifications

but what I want is this: http://example.com/gods/notifications

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
resources :gods, :only => [:index] do
  collection do
    get :notifications      
  end
end
```

You can read more details about this here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is, change your current route to this:

```
match "/gods/:id/notifications" => "gods#notifications"
```